# Detecting and manipulating CKEditor areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, wysiwyg

I need to write a javascript function that can look at the WYSIWYG on the page (CKEditor) that is rendered after the page loads with the Drupal WYSIWYG module. I am having difficulty using jQuery even finding the editor.

$(textarea#textarea-id).change or .keyup do nothing.

I can do this:

```
console.log(CKEDITOR.instances);
```

That at least shows me the instance where CKEditor is attaching itself to. I can't seem to reference anything after that:

CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance-name or CKEDITOR.instances[0] both return undefined.

I've gone in circles for 2 hours now and not sure what else to try.

All I want to do is when the user is typing (keyup), count the characters input. If the input is greater than a certain length, I want to force a line break right in the text.

How can I go about implementing this? I thought it would be fairly straightforward.

Using other examples I have seen:

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
  CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() {alert('test 1 2 3')});
}
```

Resulted in no alert.

The editor is being loaded/displayed in an iframe (via CKEditor/WYSIWYG in Drupal).

Comment: Your CKEDITOR instance should be visible through CKEDITOR.instances["instance_name"]. Could you offer me a link to your page?

Comment: Can't. Under development on my local machine. When I try to log the above statement, I get 'undefined'.

Comment: Then post your code at http://pastebin.com or http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: The instance name is 'edit-description-value' and the dash is causing a problem

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin available that provides an onChange event for CKEditor, you can find it (along with instructions) [here](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html).

It suggests using code like this:

```
editor.on( 'saveSnapshot', function(e) { somethingChanged(); });
```